# How to avoid wasted gerrit review submits?

Tags: workflow, gerrit

Over the last year of using ~5 different gerrit servers I encountered a common issue: while performing the review, someone did +2 and submitted the change, so your entire review effort become useless.

How can we avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a special strategy to "lock" the approval and to "unlock" it after a timeout. For example:

1) Create a custom label on Gerrit (ex: timeout)

2) Set [gerrit-trigger](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) on Jenkins to trigger a job for every patchset pushed to Gerrit. For every patchset do the following:

2.1) Set label timeout = -1 (lock).

2.2) Save in a file the change number with the time when it will be unlocked.

3) Set on Jenkins a periodical job to look for timeout changes in the lock file. Set label timeout = +1 (unlock) when it's needed.

Some people with +1 permission on label timeout can bypass the timeout period if needed.

Comment: Seems like a lot of code (and bugs) to write but it should work in  he end. I wonder if there is something similar to this already written. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I was not yet able to find an acceptable solution, I ended up proposing 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=7073 feature which is a configurable cool-down period needed before the server would allow someone to perform **submit**.

I am aware that a common approach is to ask for `2x +2` votes before allowing a submit but this approach has two issues:

- it does not solve the original issue: you could easily be the 3rd person writing the review
- slows down the process to a level that even makes it impossible to apply for some projects (few committers, unreliable response time)

PS. Clearly this answer does not count as an acceptable solution.